# How to escape new line characters for json?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, json

I have a file that contains new line characters.
I am posting the file via `curl` to a server that would parse it as json.
It rejects the request due to the new line characters.
But when I do:

```
$(echo "$MY_DATA" | sed 's/$//' | tr -d '\n\r')
```

It works but the new line characters are gone.
How can I escape the text so that it keeps the new line characters?
I tried `tr '\n' '\\n'` and `sed 's/\n/\\n/g` and neither approach worked

Comment: *to a server that would parse it as json* - what's your `$MY_DATA` value and expected result

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest: It is just a 2 line string (all ascii) 
with a new line char between. The only change I do for it to work is remove the new line.

Comment: you wrote *for json*, if it's JSON string - post its value

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I assume you want to change raw newline characters to `\n` (a backslash and an `n`).

`tr '\n' '\\n'` would change newlines to backslashes (and then there's an extra `n` in the second set). `sed 's/\n/\\n/g` won't work because `sed` doesn't load the line-terminating newline into the buffer, but handles it internally.

Some alternatives are GNU sed with `-z` (takes the input as NUL-separated "lines", not newline-separated):

```
sed -z 's/\n/\\n/g'
```

and Perl (unlike sed, it *does* take the newline in the buffer, so `s///` works on it):

```
perl -pe 's/\n/\\n/g'
```

(`tr -d '\n\r'` will indeed remove newlines, that's exactly what you're asking it to do.)

Comment: You may want to format the json as one line, as this could mess up the formatting and make it invalid.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you. I didn't get the part about: ` then there's an extra n in the second set`. So `tr '\n' '\\n'` would replace `\n` with `\\`? and then append an `n`? So the result would be `\\n` but it wouldn't be considered new line char?

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor: What do you mean?

Comment: @Jim, `tr` takes two sets of characters (or bytes), and converts the ones in the first set to the ones in the second. `\n` is one character after the backslash-escape  is processed, `\\n` is two. The `n` just doesn't do anything. It never changes one character to two. `tr 'ab' '\\n'` would change `a` to a backslash, and `b` to `n`.

Comment: @Jim, and I think they mean that if your input has newlines _outside_ quoted strings, the simple substitution will change them to `\n`, and that'll break the JSON. `[1,\n2]` is fine as JSON data if the `\n` is a hard newline, but it's not fine if it's a backslash-n.

Comment: If the json has formatting, that is white space that does not affect the meaning: for example `"hello","world"` has same meaning as `"hello"    ,    "world"`. You could also have a newline in there (but not in these comments). If it got changed to `\n` (that is a back-slash and an n). Then it would not be valid json.

Comment: @ilkkachu: If I do `echo "abc" | tr 'ab' '\\n'` I get `\nc`. So `a` is replaced by a `\` which I guess is not visible to console and then `b` is replaced with `\n` which is not a new line? What is that?

Comment: @Jim, no, the `a` is translated to a literal backslash, then `b` to `n` and `c` is left unchanged. When `tr` gets the string `\\n`, it takes the two backslashes to mean a single backslash, in the same way it would take `\n` to mean a newline. `| tr 'ab' '\\x'` would be similar, you'd just get `b` changed to an `x`. There's no translation to newlines here. (yeah the comment formatting doesn't really like backslashes and backticks)

Comment: @ilkkachu:Ah I see now. I see that "echo "abc" |tr 'ab' 'z\n'" actually converts to new line char

Answer (score 10):

Use `jq` to properly JSON encode the data:

```
printf '%s' "$MY_DATA" | jq -sR .
```

The `-s` (`--slurp`) and `-R` (`--raw-input`) options, when used together, will read the raw input data and create a single JSON-encoded string out of it.

Example:

```bsh
MY_DATA='line 1
line 2 contains a literal tab   <-- there
line 3 "the end"'

printf '%s' "$MY_DATA" | jq -sR .
```

Output:

```json
"line 1\nline 2 contains a literal tab\t<-- there\nline 3 \"the end\""
```

Comment: Thanks, just what I was looking for, totally forgot to check `jq`! This did the job for me when I wanted to `curl -X POST` the content of a text file: `jq -sR < myfile.txt`.